# Jasmine + Angular2: This test module uses the component Login which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

I'm currently integrating unit tests to my angular 2 project. I'm able to test services, but I have problems testing components, which are using a templateUrl to fetch an external template. I guess the problem is related to webpack, which is resolving the path/directories incorrectly. Here is my test-file.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BasePage } from '../../base/base.page';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

describe('Page: LoginPage', () => {
let page: LoginPage;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [BasePage, LoginPage],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
  });

  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
  page = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('Page: LoginPage should create a `FormGroup` comprised of `FormControl`s', async(() => {
  TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
    page = fixture.componentInstance;
    page.ngOnInit();

    expect(page).toBeDefined();
    expect(page.loginForm instanceof FormGroup).toBe(true);

    expect(Object.keys(page.loginForm.controls)).toEqual([
      'email', 'password'
    ]);
  });
}));
```

});

When I'm running the tests, the output on the console is the following:

```
    WARN [web-server]: 404: /login.page.html
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Page: LoginPage Page: LoginPage should create a `FormGroup` comprised of `FormControl`s FAILED
    Error: This test module uses the component LoginPage which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test. in spec-bundle.js (line 15105)
```

I also tried to load the template with template: require('raw!./login.page.html') instead of templateUrl: 'login.page.html'. But then the test still fails due to a template parse Error:

```
    Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "h4" (" col-lg-4 offset-lg-4\">\n            <h4 class=\"card-title\">{{ 'pages.login.title' | translate }}[
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `compileComponents` *before* you try to create the component. In the `beforeEach` you are trying to create the component before calling `compileComponents`. Just remove that.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [BasePage, LoginPage],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
  });

  // const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
  // page = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

**EDIT**

> I guess the problem is related to webpack

*Actually*, with Webpack you shouldn't need to call `compileComponents`, because when using Webpack, you should get the templates taken from the `templateUrl` and compiled into `templates`. You should make sure that for the test config, you're using the `'angular2-template-loader'`. You can have a look at [this basic webpack configuration](https://github.com/psamsotha/angular2-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the beforeEach async as the template fetching process is asynchronous. Also you need to call complileComponent after calling configureTestingModule and then create your component.
  `

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [BasePage, LoginPage],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
  }).compileComponent().then(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
  page = fixture.componentInstance;
})
}));
```

`